# Java: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Tags: java

So users on my game can have figure codes like `ch-255-110.hr-165-1394.hd-180-1380.lg-280-110`, I am trying to only fetch certain parts of this figure code, but I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Exception message:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

Here is the line of code at the highest leve:

```
hairPart = look.split("hr")[1].split(".")[0];
```

Whole method:

```
public static String splitFigure(String look) {
    String hairPart = "";
    String headPart = "";
    String headAccPart = "";
    String hatPart = "";
    String glassesPart = "";
    String beardPart = "";
    String chestPart = "";
    String jacketPart = "";
    String necklacePart = "";
    String pantsPart = "";
    String beltPart = "";
    String shoesPart = "";

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("hr"))
    {
        hairPart = look.split("hr")[1].split(".")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("hd"))
    {
        headPart = look.split("hd")[1].split(".")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("he"))
    {
        headAccPart = look.split("he")[1].split(".")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("ha"))
    {
        hatPart = look.split("ha")[1].split(".")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("ea"))
    {
        glassesPart = look.split("ea")[1].split(".")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("fa"))
    {
        beardPart = look.split("fa")[1].split(".")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("ch"))
    {
        chestPart = look.split("ch")[1].split(".")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("cc"))
    {
        jacketPart = look.split("cc")[1].split(".")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("ca"))
    {
        necklacePart = look.split("ca")[1].split(".")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("lg"))
    {
        pantsPart = look.split("lg")[1].split(".")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("wa"))
    {
        beltPart = look.split("wa")[1].split(".")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("sh"))
    {
        shoesPart = look.split("sh")[1].split(".")[0];
    }

    return "ha" + hatPart + "." + "he" + headAccPart + "." + "hr" + hairPart + "." + "hd" + headPart + "." + "ea" + glassesPart + "." + "fa" + beardPart + "." + "ch" + chestPart + "." + "cc" + jacketPart + "." + "ca" + necklacePart + "." + "lg" + pantsPart + "." + "wa" + beltPart + "." + "sh" + shoesPart + ".";
}
```

Example of what I passed in:

```
ch-255-110.hr-165-1394.hd-180-1380.lg-280-110
```

Comment: Not an answer, but if you want to split on dot, then you probably want `split("\\.")`, since dot is a regex metacharacter.  Not sure your problem is reproducible though.

Comment: How do you call this method?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post the string that you want method `splitFigure` to return?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this instead:

```
look.split("hr")[1].split("\\.")[0]
```

Checked with this

```
String a = "ch-255-110.hr-165-1394.hd-180-1380.lg-280-110";
System.out.println(a.split("hr")[1].split("\\.")[0]);
```

Not sure why it's happening but I once faced a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String look = "ch-255-110.hr-165-1394.hd-180-1380.lg-280-110";
    
    splitFigure(look);
    
    System.out.println(look);
}


public static String splitFigure(String look) {
    String hairPart = "";
    String headPart = "";
    String headAccPart = "";
    String hatPart = "";
    String glassesPart = "";
    String beardPart = "";
    String chestPart = "";
    String jacketPart = "";
    String necklacePart = "";
    String pantsPart = "";
    String beltPart = "";
    String shoesPart = "";

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("hr"))
    {
        hairPart = look.split("hr")[1].split("\\.")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("hd"))
    {
        headPart = look.split("hd")[1].split("\\.")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("he"))
    {
        headAccPart = look.split("he")[1].split("\\.")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("ha"))
    {
        hatPart = look.split("ha")[1].split("\\.")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("ea"))
    {
        glassesPart = look.split("ea")[1].split("\\.")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("fa"))
    {
        beardPart = look.split("fa")[1].split("\\.")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("ch"))
    {
        chestPart = look.split("ch")[1].split("\\.")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("cc"))
    {
        jacketPart = look.split("cc")[1].split("\\.")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("ca"))
    {
        necklacePart = look.split("ca")[1].split("\\.")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("lg"))
    {
        pantsPart = look.split("lg")[1].split("\\.")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("wa"))
    {
        beltPart = look.split("wa")[1].split("\\.")[0];
    }

    if (look.toLowerCase().contains("sh"))
    {
        shoesPart = look.split("sh")[1].split("\\.")[0];
    }

    return "ha" + hatPart + "." + "he" + headAccPart + "." + "hr" + hairPart + "." + 
    "hd" + headPart + "." + "ea" + glassesPart + "." + "fa" + beardPart + "." + "ch" + 
    chestPart + "." + "cc" + jacketPart + "." + "ca" + necklacePart + "." + "lg" + 
    pantsPart + "." + "wa" + beltPart + "." + "sh" + shoesPart + ".";
}
```